# A cryptic (for fun and diversion)

Tags: cryptic-clues

Okay, here's the cryptic:

bbbbbb connect recursively (4)

Enjoy!

Comment: If you solve it, please give feedback!

Comment: Is it from a crossword?

Comment: No, I came up with this myself.

Comment: rot13(oooooo vf n pbybe (tenl), n fbat anzr, naq na Vprynaqvp erpbeq ynory. Hasbeghangryl, vg qbrfa'g frrz gb or gur anzr bs n onaq, juvpu jbhyq unir orra vqrny, nf 'onaq (gbtrgure nf n tebhc)' pna zrna 'pbaarpg erphefviryl'. )

Comment: @Amoz Guvax zber pnershyyl nobhg vg. V qba'g yvxr hfvat urk va pelcgvpf... Good find, though, I didn't even know about that label!

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to this may be

> LOOP

Reasoning

> The "bbbbbb" part may represent a repeated instruction (as for a computer) which keeps printing the same letter over and over (a computational loop).
>  On the other hand, "connect recursively" might be a way to describe the physical act of forming a loop (as in the verb, *to loop*).